# How to get all IP addresses that are not in a given range of IP addresses

Tags: algorithm, network-programming, ip, salesforce, apex

I need to be able to output all the ranges of IP addresses that are not in a given list of IP addresses ranges.

There is some sort of algorithm that I can use for this kind of task that I can transform into working code?

- Basically I will use Salesforce Apex code, so any JAVA like language will do if a given example is possible.

Comment: How is a range specified? X.X.X.X/Y?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - X.X.X.X to Y.Y.Y.Y

Comment: @GoldenAxe your task relates only to IPv4? (meaning no IPv6 addresses)

Comment: What's the wider problem you are trying to solve? The platform itself may be able to help you depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 1):

I think the key for an easy solution is to remember IP addresses can be treated as a number of type long, and so they can be sorted.

I assumed the excluded ranges are given in a "nice" way, meaning no overlaps, no partial overlaps with global range and so on. You can of course add such input checks later on.

In this example I'll to all network ranges (global, included, excluded) as instances of `NetworkRange` class.

Following is the implementation of `NetworkRange`. Pay attention to the methods `splitByExcludedRange` and `includes`.

```
public class NetworkRange {

    private long startAddress;
    private long endAddress;

    public NetworkRange(String start, String end) {
        startAddress = addressRepresentationToAddress(start);
        endAddress = addressRepresentationToAddress(end);
    }

    public NetworkRange(long start, long end) {
        startAddress = start;
        endAddress   = end;
    }

    public String getStartAddress() {
        return addressToAddressRepresentation(startAddress);
    }

    public String getEndAddress() {
        return addressToAddressRepresentation(endAddress);
    }

    static String addressToAddressRepresentation(long address) {
        String result = String.valueOf(address % 256);

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            address = address / 256;
            result = String.valueOf(address % 256) + "." + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static long addressRepresentationToAddress(String addressRep) {
        long result = 0L;
        String[] tokens = addressRep.split("\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            result += Math.pow(256, i) * Long.parseLong(tokens[3-i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public List<NetworkRange> splitByExcludedRange(NetworkRange excludedRange) {
        if (this.startAddress == excludedRange.startAddress && this.endAddress == excludedRange.endAddress)
            return Arrays.asList();

        if (this.startAddress == excludedRange.startAddress)
            return Arrays.asList(new NetworkRange(excludedRange.endAddress+1, this.endAddress));

        if (this.endAddress == excludedRange.endAddress)
            return Arrays.asList(new NetworkRange(this.startAddress, excludedRange.startAddress-1));

        return Arrays.asList(new NetworkRange(this.startAddress, excludedRange.startAddress-1),
                             new NetworkRange(excludedRange.endAddress+1, this.endAddress));
    }

    public boolean includes(NetworkRange excludedRange) {
        return this.startAddress <= excludedRange.startAddress && this.endAddress >= excludedRange.endAddress;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" + getStartAddress() + "-" + getEndAddress() + "]";
    }
}
```

Now comes the class that calculates the network ranges left included. It accepts a global range in constructor.

```
public class RangeProducer {

    private NetworkRange global;

    public RangeProducer(NetworkRange global) {
     this.global = global;
    }

    public List<NetworkRange> computeEffectiveRanges(List<NetworkRange> excludedRanges) {
        List<NetworkRange> effectiveRanges = new ArrayList<>();
        effectiveRanges.add(global);
        List<NetworkRange> effectiveRangesSplitted = new ArrayList<>();

        for (NetworkRange excludedRange : excludedRanges) {
            for (NetworkRange effectiveRange : effectiveRanges) {
                if (effectiveRange.includes(excludedRange)) {
                    effectiveRangesSplitted.addAll(effectiveRange.splitByExcludedRange(excludedRange));
                } else {
                    effectiveRangesSplitted.add(effectiveRange);
                }
            }

            effectiveRanges = effectiveRangesSplitted;
            effectiveRangesSplitted = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return effectiveRanges;
    }
}
```

You can run the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NetworkRange global = new NetworkRange("10.0.0.0", "10.255.255.255");

        NetworkRange ex1 = new NetworkRange("10.0.0.0", "10.0.1.255");
        NetworkRange ex2 = new NetworkRange("10.1.0.0", "10.1.1.255");
        NetworkRange ex3 = new NetworkRange("10.6.1.0", "10.6.2.255");
        List<NetworkRange> excluded = Arrays.asList(ex1, ex2, ex3);

        RangeProducer producer = new RangeProducer(global);

        for (NetworkRange effective : producer.computeEffectiveRanges(excluded)) {
            System.out.println(effective);
        }
    }
```

Output should be:

```
[10.0.2.0-10.0.255.255]
[10.1.2.0-10.6.0.255]
[10.6.3.0-10.255.255.255]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you mean that you get one or more disjoint CIDR ranges as input, and need to produce the list of all CIDR ranges not including any of the ones given as input. For convenience, let's further assume that the input does not include the entire IP address space: i.e. `0.0.0.0/0`. (That can be accommodated with a single special case but is not of much interest.)

I've written code analogous to this before and, though I'm not at liberty to share the code, I can describe the methodology. It's essentially a binary search algorithm wherein you bisect the full address space repeatedly until you've isolated the one range you're interested in.

Think of the IP address space as a binary tree: At the root is the full IPv4 address space `0.0.0.0/0`. Its children each represent half of the address space: `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1.` Those, in turn, can be sub-divided to create children `0.0.0.0/2` / `64.0.0.0/2` and `128.0.0.0/2` / `192.0.0.0/2,` respectively. Continue this all the way down and you end up with `2**32` leaves, each of which represents a single `/32` (i.e. a single address).

Now, consider this tree to be the parts of the address space that are excluded from your input list. So your task is to traverse this tree, find each range from your input list in the tree, and cut out all parts of the tree that are in your input, leaving the remaining parts of the address space.

Fortunately, you needn't actually create all the `2**32` leaves. Each node at CIDR `N` can be assumed to include all nodes at CIDR `N+1` and above if no children have been created for it (you'll need a flag to remember that it has already been subdivided -- *i.e.* is no longer a leaf -- see below for why).

So, to start, the entire address space is present in the tree, but can all be represented by a single leaf node. Call the tree `excluded,` and initialize it with the single node `0.0.0.0/0.`

Now, take the first input range to consider -- we'll call this `trial` (I'll use `14.27.34.0/24` as the initial `trial` value just to provide a concrete value for demonstration). The task is to remove `trial` from `excluded` leaving the rest of the address space.

Start with `current` node pointer set to the `excluded` root node.

**Start:**

Compare the `trial` CIDR with `current`. If it is identical, you're done (but this should never happen if your input ranges are disjoint and you've excluded `0.0.0.0/0` from input).

Otherwise, if `current` is a leaf node (has not been subdivided, meaning it represents the entire address space at this CIDR level and below), set its sub-divided flag, and create two children for it: a `left` pointer to the first half of its address space, and a `right` pointer to the latter half. Label each of these appropriately (for the root node's children, that will be `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`).

Determine whether the `trial` CIDR falls within the left side or the right side of `current`. For our initial `trial` value, it's to the left. Now, if the pointer on that side is already `NULL`, again you're done (though again that "can't happen" if your input ranges are disjoint).

If the `trial` CIDR is *exactly* equivalent to the CIDR in the node on that side, then simply free the node (and any children it might have, which again should be none if you have only disjoint inputs), set the pointer to that side `NULL` and you're done. You've just excluded that entire range by cutting that leaf out of the tree.

If the trial value is not exactly equivalent to the CIDR in the node on that side, set `current` to that side and start over (i.e. jump to **Start** label above).

So, with the initial input range of `14.27.34.0/24`, you will first split `0.0.0.0/0` into `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`. You will then drop down on the left side and split `0.0.0.0/1` into `0.0.0.0/2` and `64.0.0.0/2.` You will then drop down to the left again to create `0.0.0.0/3` and `32.0.0.0/3.` And so forth, until after 23 splits, you will then split `14.27.34.0/23` into `14.27.34.0/24` and `14.27.35.0/24.` You will then delete the left-hand `14.27.34.0/24` child node and set its pointer to `NULL`, leaving the other.

That will leave you with a sparse tree containing 24 leaf nodes (after you dropped the target one). The remaining leaf nodes are marked with *:

```
                             (ROOT)
                           0.0.0.0/0
                            /     \
                      0.0.0.0/1  128.0.0.0/1*
                        /    \
                 0.0.0.0/2  64.0.0.0/2*
                  /     \
            0.0.0.0/3  32.0.0.0.0/3*
              /    \
       0.0.0.0/4  16.0.0.0/4*
           /  \
  *0.0.0.0/5  8.0.0.0/5
               /    \
       *8.0.0.0/6  12.0.0.0/6
                      /    \
             *12.0.0.0/7  14.0.0.0/7
                             /    \
                     14.0.0.0/8  15.0.0.0/8*
                        /    \
                     ...
                /       \
     *14.27.32.0/23  14.27.34.0/23
                      /       \
                  (null)     14.27.35.0/24*
          (14.27.34.0/24)
```

For each remaining input range, you will run through the tree again, bisecting leaf nodes when necessary, often resulting in more leaves, but always cutting out some part of the address space.

At the end, you simply traverse the resulting tree in whatever order is convenient, collecting the CIDRs of the remaining leaves. Note that in this phase you *must* exclude those that have previously been subdivided. Consider for example, in the above tree, if you next processed input range `14.27.35.0/24`, you would leave `14.27.34.0/23` with no children, but both its halves have been separately cut out and it should not be included in the output. (With some additional complication, you could of course collapse nodes above it to accommodate that scenario as well, but it's easier to just keep a flag in each node.)

Comment: As said the format is X.X.X.X to Y.Y.Y.Y, you can look at this as a list of IP range objects each item in the list contains Start-IP and End-IP. I was thinking of ordering the list in ascending order, loop on it, and create a new list with the ranges in between. With special cases for the start of the list and end of the list. Does this solution is valid?
* Assume we don't have overlaps.

Comment: This solution works for *any* set of ranges, since any range can be decomposed into a list of valid CIDR-formatted ranges -- though individual members of the list might end up being /32 (i.e. single host).

Answer (score 0):

First, what you describe can be simplified to:

- you have intervals of the form x.x.x.x - y.y.y.y
- you want to output the intervals that are not yet "taken" in this range.
- you want to be able to add or remove intervals efficiently

I would suggest the use of an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), where each node stores an interval, and you can efficiently insert and remove nodes; and query for overlaps at a given point (= IP address).

If you can guarantee that there will be no overlaps, you can instead use a simple `TreeSet<String>`, where you must however guarantee (for correct sorting) that all strings use the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy` zero-padded format.

Once your intervals are in a tree, you can then generate your desired output, assuming that no intervals overlap, by performing a depth-first pre-order traversal of your tree, and storing the starts and ends of each visited node in a list. Given this list,

- pre-pend 0.0.0.0 at the start
- append 255.255.255.255 at the end
- remove all duplicate ips (which will forcefully be right next to each other in the list)
- take them by pairs (the number will always be even), and there you have the intervals of free IPs, perfectly sorted.

Note that [0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) and [255.255.255.255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) are not actually valid, routable IPs. You should read the relevant RFCs if you really need to output real-world-aware IPs.